# How to Bind Odometer in Datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I downloaded Odometer Sample from http://uvumitools.com/odometer.html
but only the First Element in the Datalist getting the Odometer, others not Displaying the 
Ododmeter.
 Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/UvumiOdometer-compressed.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/uvumi-odometer.css"
<script type="text/javascript">
  var odo2 = new UvumiOdometer('odometer2', { digits: 3 });
</script>`
```

`<asp:DataList ID="dlEquipment" runat="server" DataKeyField="Device_Id"
     RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="5" Width="100 >
     <ItemTemplate>
    <div id="odometer2<%# Eval("count")%>
    </div></ItemTemplate>`

Comment: Post code sample so we can help

Comment: @ michael-b sample code posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have more than one element with same ID,  it worked only for first one..

Change Item template to include the script -that initializes new odometer - so it will populate different id for odemter div based on any key column

try this

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div id='odometer<%# Eval("Device_Id") %>'>
        <%# Eval("count")%>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        new UvumiOdometer('odometer<%# Eval("Device_Id")%>', { digits: 3 });
    </script>

</ItemTemplate>
```

- I'm assuming that "Device_Id" is a unique column

Comment: the code working fine on google chrome but internet explorer 9 is not supporting this code

Comment: @ michael Actually there is no error the odometer is not displaying in firefox and Internet explorer instead The count is Displaying(<%# Eval("count")%>)

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are using a static id odometer2 in a list element, ID in a document should be unique else the document.getElementById(id) will always return the first element with the given id.

if you are using jQuery you can add a class attribute to the div

```
<ItemTemplate> <div class="odometer2"> </div></ItemTemplate>
then
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $('.odometer2').each(function(){
        new UvumiOdometer(this, { digits: 3 });
    })
})
</script>
```